# What is the meaning of "something AND 1=0" command in SQL?

Tags: attacks, sql-injection, mysql

I have read somewhere that in SQL injection attacks the attackers use such keywords into application entry points. Whats the purpose of doing  this?

Comment: Please do more research before asking.  As the site's page explains, [this site is for for Information Security professionals](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  If you have a question about a basic topic like SQL injection, I expect you to do research first to read existing resources about SQL injection before asking here.  In this case, your question is well covered by existing resources, so there would not be a lot of point in us duplicating all of those existing resources. Why don't you tell us what study and research you have done and what specifically you found confusing?

Comment: Also in the future you should give the precise reference where you saw this, so people have enough context to explain it for you.

Comment: See also http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8761/971

Comment: @mac For balance, we also have the [Ask] page, clearly stating  prior research requirement. Mostly to avoid needless duplication of contents, but it should also prevent trivial questions being asked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fragment `AND 1=0` always evaluates to `false` and therefore the query always returns an empty set, e.g. if the SQL fragment in the application is

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '<placeholder>'
```

then I can turn this query to

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' AND 1=0 --'
```

when using `admin' AND 1=0 --` as value for the placeholder.

I can now insert a second statement which is executed instead of the intended one, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' AND 1=0; TRUNCATE TABLE users; --'
```

Here I will empty the table `users` as attack.

Another thing used is `OR 1=1` which always evaluated to `true`. This is used to query a whole table and eliminate the where-caluse completely, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' OR 1=1 --'
```

This is achieved by using `admin' OR 1=1 --` as the placeholder in the above example.

In this case the complete table `users` will be returned.

Comment: Why not just say SELECT * from users, why do you need to add the additional WHERE statement?

Comment: @GdD, remember this is an attack against a website.  The website's original code is "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = " and you enter "'admin' OR 1=1" If you concatenate these values you get "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' OR 1=1" which will return the whole user table.

Comment: @GdD edited answer to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see @ChrisMurray, because the value is not sanitized it will simply run it as-is.

Comment: Since `… OR 1=1` is true for all records, you may also alter/delete all records if it’s not a SELECT but an UPDATE or DELETE statement which gets executed.

Comment: or it could be [someone's legitimate name](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Timmy You’ll never need to link to that comic again, because there is an actual company in Poland called [Dariusz Jakubowski x'; DROP TABLE users; SELECT '1](https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/ceidg.public.ui/SearchDetails.aspx?Id=e82735cd-bc2b-4ac0-8bac-a1dc54d8c013) to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 6):

`1=0` is always false, so a clause containing `AND 1=0` will also always be false.  This, like the always-true `OR 1=1`, can be used to bypass the conditions in a `WHERE` clause.

The `OR 1=1` variant is more generally useful (eg. `SELECT username WHERE userid=173` to get your username becomes `SELECT username WHERE userid=173 OR 1=1` to get every username on the system), but the `AND 1=0` variant can, for example, be used to bypass a "is this user already registered" check.